# Median and Boxplot (R)

Tags: r, boxplot, median

I am trying to represent graphically the Median catching time (MCT) of mosquito that we have collected. The MCT represents the time for which 50% of the total malaria vectors were caught on humans.
For example, we collected this sample:

```
Hour of collection / Mosquitoes number:
20H-21H = 1
21H-22H = 1 
22H-23H = 2 
23H-00H = 2 
00H-01H = 13 
01H-02H = 10 
02H-03H = 15 
03H-04H = 15 
04H-05H = 8 
05H-06H = 10 
06H-07H = 6
```

Here the cumulated effective is 83 mosquitoes. And I am assuming that the median of this mosquito series is (83+1)/2 = 42, inducing a Median catching time at 2 am (02H-03H).

I tried to use the function "boxplot" with different parameters, but I cannot represent what I want. Indeed, I have boxes for each hour of collection when I want the representation of the cumulated effective over the collection time. Where the time range used are "20H-21H" = 20, "21H-22H" = 21 etc.

I found an article (Nicolas Moiroux, 2012) which represents graphically the MCT as intended. I copy the image of the cited boxplot here:
[Boxplot_Moiroux2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Alwr.png)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Kind Regards.

PS, here is the code I used so far (with  "Eff" = Number of mosquito and "Heure" = time of collection):

```
sum(Eff)

as.factor(Heure)

tapply(Eff,Heure,median)
tapply(Heure,Eff,median)

boxplot(Eff,horizontal=T)

boxplot(Heure~Eff)
boxplot(Eff~Heur))
```

Comment: Can you also provide the R code of what you have done so far?

Comment: That's not how the median is defined... (even `(83 + 1) / 2` will still not give you the median)

Comment: Hi Edouard94. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: @dario He wants the median catching time, for this selecting the 42nd mosquito and taking it's time is correct. But the 42nd mosquito was caught at 3 am

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments. @geoidiot, that is correct, the 42nd mosquito was caught between 2am and 3am (if I am not wrong). So I consider it is the first hour of the time range ie 2am (02).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a trick since you already have counts and not the time data for each catch.

First, you convert your time values to a more continuous variable, then you generate a vector with all the time values and *then* you boxplot (with a custom axis).

```
txt <- "20H-21H = 1
21H-22H = 1
22H-23H = 2
23H-00H = 2
00H-01H = 13
01H-02H = 10
02H-03H = 15
03H-04H = 15
04H-05H = 8
05H-06H = 10
06H-07H = 6"

dat <- read.table(text = txt, sep = "=",  h = F)
colnames(dat) <- c("collect_time", "nb_mosquito")

# make a continuous numerical proxy for time
dat$collect_time_num <- 1:nrow(dat)

# get values of proxy according to your data
tvals <- rep(dat$collect_time_num, dat$nb_mosquito)

# plot
boxplot(tvals, horizontal = T, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, labels = as.character(dat$collect_time), at = dat$collect_time_num)
```

outputs the following plot :

[image]

Comment: hello @RoB, thank you a lot for your answer that will help me to analyse my other data. Thank you to share your knowledge and skills, it is very valuable